# could not convert string to float: 'City Hotel'

Tags: python, data-science

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train.drop('assigned_room_type', axis=1), y_train)

# test set prediction results
predictions = model.predict(X_test)
print(f'MSE: {mean_squared_error(y_true=y_test, y_pred=predictions)}')
print(f'R-Squared: {r2_score(y_test, predictions)}')
```

whenever I am trying to build a model for almost every cleaned and uncleaned dataset throwing an issue like I couldn't convert from string to float
please help me out I need to change my code or do I need to do anything while cleaning a dataset?

Comment: I suppose you are using the features which have string values. You have to convert them into numerical values and then use it in your ML model. Many methods are used for eg: One-hot encoding etc.

Comment: can you please give some information about your dataset and a precise snapshot of the error?